# Autofocus not working

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5300

I have Nikon D5300 and Nikon 18-55mm AF-P DX VR 3.5-5.6G lens.
I am no expert in photography just uses my DSLR to click normal pictures.
I always had autofocus on half shutter press and suddenly it is not working.
Images are getting clicked, but autofocus on half shutter press is not working.
I have not changed any settings.
I did factory reset, still no luck.

Comment: What is the position of the AF-MF slider on the left side of the lens?

Comment: @xenoid I do not have slider on side of lens.

Comment: Have you tried unmounting the lens and mounting it again?

Comment: @PeterTaylor yes done that

Comment: Maybe you have set your camera to MF? Is the Problem only in Viewfinder mode or also in Liveview?

Answer (score 1):

[Ken Rockwell says](https://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/18-55mm-af-p.htm) :

> Nikon cautions that you need to have the latest firmware installed for
>   it to work on the D5500, D5300 or D3300.
>
> The problem is that the new AF-P autofocus motor system only works on
>   camera models originally introduced since about 2013. If your camera
>   is too old, the focus system, even in manual mode, won't work at all,
>   making the lens completely useless with no workaround.

So it sounds like there might be a camera firmware solution for the D5300 - unless you're already using the latest version.

Comment: But OP said it was working, and suddenly is not working.

Comment: I have the latest firmware. when i press half press shutter, motor does move trying to focus

Comment: @PrakashKumar please edit your question to add that information. The fact that the motor moves while trying to focus is important to know, and helps people provide better answers and advice, rather than guessing or slowly learning bits of information piece by piece.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean the contacts on the lens? Sometimes some dust or debris needs attention.

Answer (score -1):

The D5300 User Manual shows the 18-55mm lens does have an AF slide switch on the side of the lens, next to the VR slider there too.  The switch is marked A-M, with A being Auto Focus mode, and M being Manual focus (no Auto Focus).

The D5300 "User Manual" on Page 81 and also Page 16 shows this AF slide switch on the lens.

The D5300 "Reference Manual" is much larger and more complete than the "User Manual" and is worthwhile and free from Nikon at 
https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/25/D5300.html

And it mentions there is also a Manual focus menu on page 51.

Comment: https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-p-dx-nikkor-18-55mm-f%252f3.5-5.6g-vr.html  I have this lens, there is not slide for AF switch. even the manual focus is not working

Comment: What do you mean by "even the manual focus is not working"?

Comment: in reference manual it is mentioned, how to use manual focus, I tried it, but it did not work. Normally by half press shutter autofocus worked, but suddenly it stopped

Comment: But does *manual focus* work?

Comment: @WayneF I'm pretty sure the instructions in that manual are generic, and don't necessarily apply to this lens in specific.

Comment: @mattdm   Maybe so, but D5300 User Manual page 81 shows A-M switch specifically on AF-S DX Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR.  There is a version II of it now, but manual does not say II.

Comment: @WayneF I'm following your link. There is a picture on pages 82-83 (of the US version of the user manual) which clearly shows a mode switch on the AF-S `II` version, but _not_ on the AF-P version — which is what Prakash says they are using.

Comment: Yes, I have AF-P lens, which does not have switch nor my body.

Comment: Ah so, thanks. They added that second page to the current user manual, but I was unaware, and was looking at an older version I had on local disk (without that added page). It does not say II, but it clearly shows switches as on II. Seems odd now too that the first lens has VR, but also no VR switch.